# Как корректно определить webkit браузер и ос windows?

Tags: jquery, webkit, html, javascript

Привет подскажите способ вернуть "true" если браузер webkit и ос windows!

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится,сделал примерно так:

```
var isFontAliasing = function() {
    return (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) && ('WebkitAppearance' in document.documentElement.style);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Браузер - http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/DJ349/

ОС -

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

Comment: Замечательно, теперь ещё заподозрить webkit (chrome,новая opera,всякие яндекс браузеры)